# Error when add image to project

Tags: react-native

I created a project and then added an image in the project root directory.

In my index.android.js I added:

When run react-native run android, the error is displayed:

error: bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module `./my-icon.png` from `C:\\Users\\Ayala\\Documents\\Developer\\React\\BrunoDantas\\index.android.js`: could not resolve `C:\Users\Ayala\Documents\Developer\React\BrunoDantas\my-icon.png' as a folder: it did not contain a package, nor an index file"

Comment: Try `../my-icon.png` << two dots

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your path I think your code example is missing.  But the problem is that the image is not able to be found.

Currently your code is I believe?

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

This means the image should be in the same folder as your index.android.js which I'm guessing it's not...  We would need more information in order to tell you what the real problem is.

Comment: my class:

export default class BrunoDantas extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
         <Image
          source={require('./logoimg.png')}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Comment: is the error above still the same error and is logoimg.png in the same directory as this class?